# How to make jagged text using CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to display some text on a low-quality image background. So instead of smooth text, I want to show jagged text like.

[image]

I tried to scale small text using `transform: scale()`, blur text using `text-shadow`, `font-smoothing:none` but it can not make jagged text.

How can I do this using CSS (or Javascript)?

Comment: Do you need the text to be copyable?

Comment: yes, it better if it's still copyable, but if there is no solution, none copyable may be ok

Comment: Non-copyable jagged text is possible by using `fillText` in a Canvas, then in CSS using `image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;` and a `scale` transform.

Comment: Thank you, I think your idea is possible. however, because my current code is using `p` tag for text instead of canvas so maybe I will try to find an easier solution then I will switch to canvas if there is no easy solution

Comment: There’s also the [CSS `element` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element%28%29) that `image-rendering` and `scale` also apply to. But it also doesn’t offer copyability. You might find some SVG filter that does this. But so far, it seems that you need the path from text to bitmap to scaled up bitmap, and bitmaps cannot be copied as text.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191293/how-to-get-an-aliased-retro-style-html-text-effect/65191458#65191458

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you're after, but [font-smooth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) might be close.

```
font-smooth: never;
```

It is not standards compliant, so be careful where you use it.
On Chrome, I had to prefix it with `webkit-`

Edit: On Chrome it seems to be `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;`

Comment: I tried it `-webkit-font-smooth: never;`, tested on Chrome and Edge but it don't make jagged text (my current text font is Arial)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I wonder if it's a Mac specific thing. Here's how it looks if I just disable it for the heading on this page https://imgur.com/a/02KpwoY

Comment: Just added a small clarification for Chrome if you want to give that a go

Comment: Currently, I am using Window, after I add `-webkit-font-smoothing: none;`, the font doesn't change. I read from this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth, it look like `-webkit-font-smooth: never;` only work in MacOS